# Append a JSX element in React by pushing to array and using React Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to append a `div` with two text fields whenever the user clicks a button.

I'm trying to do so by using `useState` and pushing the new JSX element to an array.

But I'm having a couple of problems:

- When clicking the button the first time, instead of the new elements in the DOM, I see the number 2, which seems to be the length of the array.
- By clicking the button again, I get the error `linksArray.push is not a function`.

```
function LinkFieldsSet() {
    return (
        <div>
            <TextField label="Text" />
            <TextField label="URL" />
        </div>
    )
}

function Links() {

    const [{linksArray, keyNum}, setState] = React.useState({
        linksArray: [<LinkFieldsSet key={1} />],
        keyNum: 1,
    });

    const handleAddClick = () => {
        setState({
            keyNum: keyNum + 1,
            linksArray: linksArray.push(<LinkFieldsSet key={keyNum} />)
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {linksArray}
            <AddRowsButton action={handleAddClick} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `linksArray: linksArray.push(<LinkFieldsSet key={keyNum} />` pushes the element to `linksArray` and `returns the new length of the array`. So after this line your `linksArray` is a number.

Also, `{linksArray}` jsx binding is a bit incorrect as for me.

Try this:

```
function Links() {
  const [{ linksArray, keyNum }, setState] = React.useState({
    linksArray: [<LinkFieldsSet key={1} />],
    keyNum: 1
  });

  const handleAddClick = () => {
    linksArray.push(<LinkFieldsSet key={keyNum + 1} />);
    setState({
      keyNum: keyNum + 1,
      linksArray: linksArray
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {linksArray.map((x) => x)}
      <AddRowsButton action={handleAddClick} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be with `handleAddClick` method. `Array.push` would not return an Array, use `Array.concat` instead. Update `handleAddClick` as below,

```js
const handleAddClick = () => {
    const newKeyNum = keyNum + 1;
    setState({
        keyNum: newKeyNum,
        linksArray: linksArray.concat(<LinkFieldsSet key={newKeyNum} />)
    });
};
```